# "The RPC server is unavailable" using WMI query

Tags: c#, asp.net, wmi, rpc, wmi-query

I have a workgroup of web servers running Server 2008 R2 in which I'm trying to manage a script that checks the disk space of all of them. I had set this up a few months ago when the servers were being set up and I believe it was working fine. Now I go and check and it's giving an error saying "The RPC server is unavailable". The script is a C# ASP.NET page, though I've tried comparable calls in PowerShell and it gives the same error. The script works fine to access the information for the local machine, but can't access remote server info.

I've spent the last few hours digging through everything I can find, but nothing works. I've set permissions for WMI (remote & local), DCOM (remote & local), and the whole drive of the computer I'm accessing. I've used the computer name, IP address, full computer name (xxx.echomountain.com), and tried numerous impersonation and authentication settings on the ConnectionOptions object.

I know the username/passwords I'm using are correct since I can access the shard directories of one from the other

Any ideas of what else I could check that might cause this error?

```
ConnectionOptions oConn = new ConnectionOptions();
    oConn.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
    oConn.EnablePrivileges = true;
    oConn.Username = username;
    oConn.Password = password;
    //oConn.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
    string strNameSpace = @"\\";

    if (srvname != "")
        strNameSpace += srvname + ".echomountain.com";
    else
        strNameSpace += ".";

    strNameSpace += @"\root\cimv2";

    ManagementScope oMs = new ManagementScope(strNameSpace, oConn);

    //get Fixed disk state
    ObjectQuery oQuery = new ObjectQuery("select FreeSpace,Size,Name from Win32_LogicalDisk where DriveType=3");

    //Execute the query
    ManagementObjectSearcher oSearcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(oMs, oQuery);

    //Get the results
    ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();

    //loop through found drives and write out info
    double D_Freespace = 0;
    double D_Totalspace = 0;
    foreach (ManagementObject oReturn in oReturnCollection)
    {
        // Disk name
        //MessageBox.Show("Name : " + oReturn["Name"].ToString());
        // Free Space in bytes
        string strFreespace = oReturn["FreeSpace"].ToString();
        D_Freespace = D_Freespace + System.Convert.ToDouble(strFreespace);
        // Size in bytes
        string strTotalspace = oReturn["Size"].ToString();
        D_Totalspace = D_Totalspace + System.Convert.ToDouble(strTotalspace);
        boxSize = (D_Totalspace / GB).ToString("##.00");
        boxFree = (D_Freespace / GB).ToString("##.00");
        Response.Write(srvname + ":" + boxSize + ":" + boxFree);
    }
```

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 64: 
>   Line 65:         //Get the results
>   Line 66:         ManagementObjectCollection oReturnCollection = oSearcher.Get();
>   Line 67: 
>   Line 68:         //loop through found drives and write out info
>
> Source File: c:\Web\medelaimages.com\iis\tool\boxinfoagent.aspx    Line: 66
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [COMException (0x800706ba): The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)]
>      System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) +0
>      System.Management.ManagementScope.InitializeGuts(Object o) +674
>      System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize() +347
>      System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Initialize() +189
>      System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher.Get() +54
>      ASP.tool_boxinfoagent_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Web\medelaimages.com\iis\tool\boxinfoagent.aspx:66
>      System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +25
>      System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +71
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +3048
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1

Comment: I'm getting the same error but it is quite random, I mean sometimes I get this error, sometimes I don't. It looks like it depends on the kind of login I am using. How do you login? Domain account?

Comment: My logins are set up individually on each server, though they share the same credentials. I actually gave up on figuring this out. If you have it working, even intermittently, I'd be interested in how you're doing it.

Comment: Assuming your script is running on a domain machine you should not have any problems, instead if you're running outside the domain try with DOMAIN\\username as username. If I use DOMAIN\\username as login I don't get the error (most of the times).

Comment: Verify RPC is disabled by trying to map to one of the hosts' known shares. If it fails, then you know RPC is disabled, per the error message. In that case, try connecting via WMI. If WMI works, then add a comment in reply and I'll answer with a link to code that should work for you.

Answer (score 4):

The error `The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)` can occur if

- inbound RPC / WMI connections are blocked on the target machine due to Firewall restrictions

  or
- just because you entered incorrect hostname / IP address of the target machine.

The error occurs **before** any authentication and/or authorization actions, so dealing with permissions is not required at this step. In fact, if the user account lacks necessary permissions to a particular namespace, you'd get another error and errorcode: `access denied. (0x80041003)`.

The MSDN article covers adding Firewall exceptions for remote WMI access: ["Connecting to WMI Remotely"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa822854).

Answer (score 3):

The error message is telling you that RPC is blocked, which is the default policy setting on Windows 7 and 2008. Either open it via policy, or use WMI to connect and manage the hosts. On an internal, trusted network, RPC is usually enabled. US government computer security policy boards, like those that created FDCC and USGCB, have *no* recommended setting for RPC, so it is ok to enable it. Managing live systems via WMI is *very* difficult since you cannot view remote hosts' registry, scheduled tasks, folders and files. You can, however, easily manage services via WMI.

Answer (score 0):

Just Go to IIS manager. Start your website Service in Application pool.
It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Also, You need to enable Windows Management Instrumentation (WMI) rule in windows firewall on remote machine.

> 1] Open Windows Firewall.
>   2] Click on Allow app or feature through windows firewall.
>   3] Enable Privilege for Windows Management Instrumentation(WMI).

Answer (score -1):

I faced same issue. Earlier I was getting this error while using server IP but was able to connect after I used server FQDN name. After troubleshooting I found my DNS PTR record was not correct. After fixing that I was able to connect WMI with IP address also. I used wbemtest WMI test tool.