# C# - Windows Service - Remote WMI query throws error: RPC not found

Tags: c#, rpc

I am developing a WMI query windows service to query network servers.
If I run the application in console, it works as expected but the service fails to complete the WMI query. Is there any way I can setup the service so the RPC doesn't fail due to insufficient privileges? I am using credentials in the WMI query to connect to the remote PC so that should not be a problem.

Thanks

Comment: What account does the service run as?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["The RPC server is unavailable" using WMI query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224596/the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-using-wmi-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probable reason:

- Firewall configuration (RPC connections blockage)
- You don't have enough permission to run WMI queries.

Second point is valid if you are trying to run queries on remote machines. You can use `wbemtest` to verify.

1. Windows+R (run command)
2. Type wbemtest

You have to connect `ManagementScope` and check for it's validity `scope.IsConnected`. It is just a snippet of code, you might have to provide a structure to it.

```
ConnectionOptions cOption = new ConnectionOptions();
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\" + machine + "\\" + nameSpaceRoot + "\\" + managementScope, cOption);
           scope.Options.Username = UserName;
            scope.Options.Password = passWord;
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            scope.Options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy;
            //scope.Options.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
            //cOption.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180);
            scope.Options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            scope.Connect();
            return scope;



    if (scope.IsConnected && scope != null)
    {
    query = new ObjectQuery(@"Select * from Win32_SCSIController");
                            searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query); searcher.Options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, wbemConnectFlagUseMaxWait);
                            ManagementObjectCollection qWin32_SCSIController = searcher.Get();
    foreach (ManagementObject item in qWin32_SCSIController)
    {    
    <Some code here>
    }
```